# Python 2.7, AT command response, strange HEX

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyserial, at-command

From doing a USD AT command I get the following response:

> 00520030002E00300030002000610069007200740069006D0065002C0020003000200053004D005300200061006E0064002000300020004D00420020006F006600200064006100740061002E0020004400690061006C0020002A003100340031002A0031002300200066006F0072002000640065007400610069006C0073002E00200057006F005700210020005500730065002000520037002000610069007200740069006D006500200074006F00200067006500740020005200350035002B00310030004D0042002E004400690061006C0020002A003100330030002A0035003000310023

Which produces:

> ' R 0 . 0 0   a i r t i m e ,   0   S M S   a n d   0   M B   o f   d
>   a t a .   D i a l   * 1 4 1 * 1 #   f o r   d e t a i l s .   W o W ! 
>   U s e   R 7   a i r t i m e   t o   g e t   R 5 5 + 1 0 M B . D i a l 
>   * 1 3 0 * 5 0 1 #'

After running:

```
ascii = rawHex.decode("hex")
```

I figured out that there is an additional null character after each 'valid' hex digit. So instead of 52 it produces 5200

I did manage to remove the 00 after every valid hex digit by doing:

```
rawHex = ''.join( [ rawHex[i:i+2] for i in range(2,len(rawHex),4)] )
ascii = rawHex.decode("hex")
```

Which produces the correct result:

> 'R0.00 airtime, 0 SMS and 0 MB of data. Dial *141*1# for details. WoW!
>   Use R7 airtime to get R55+10MB.Dial *130*501#'

So my question: I do not know why it does this, is this a standard that I am not aware of yet?

Comment: `s = "".join(chr(int(f[i*4:(i*4)+4],16)) for i in range(len(f)/4))` f is your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)-encoded data, in big-endian order, which uses 2 bytes per character encoded. For anything in the Latin-1 range (Unicode codepoints U+0000 through to U+00FF) the most significant byte is always 00; your sample data consists of characters in the ASCII range only but I'd not count on that always being the case.

You can decode this directly without removing the null bytes by using the `utf-16-be` codec:

```
>>> rawhex = '00520030002E00300030002000610069007200740069006D0065002C0020003000200053004D005300200061006E0064002000300020004D00420020006F006600200064006100740061002E0020004400690061006C0020002A003100340031002A0031002300200066006F0072002000640065007400610069006C0073002E00200057006F005700210020005500730065002000520037002000610069007200740069006D006500200074006F00200067006500740020005200350035002B00310030004D0042002E004400690061006C0020002A003100330030002A0035003000310023'
>>> rawhex.decode('hex')
'\x00R\x000\x00.\x000\x000\x00 \x00a\x00i\x00r\x00t\x00i\x00m\x00e\x00,\x00 \x000\x00 \x00S\x00M\x00S\x00 \x00a\x00n\x00d\x00 \x000\x00 \x00M\x00B\x00 \x00o\x00f\x00 \x00d\x00a\x00t\x00a\x00.\x00 \x00D\x00i\x00a\x00l\x00 \x00*\x001\x004\x001\x00*\x001\x00#\x00 \x00f\x00o\x00r\x00 \x00d\x00e\x00t\x00a\x00i\x00l\x00s\x00.\x00 \x00W\x00o\x00W\x00!\x00 \x00U\x00s\x00e\x00 \x00R\x007\x00 \x00a\x00i\x00r\x00t\x00i\x00m\x00e\x00 \x00t\x00o\x00 \x00g\x00e\x00t\x00 \x00R\x005\x005\x00+\x001\x000\x00M\x00B\x00.\x00D\x00i\x00a\x00l\x00 \x00*\x001\x003\x000\x00*\x005\x000\x001\x00#'
>>> rawhex.decode('hex').decode('utf-16-be')
u'R0.00 airtime, 0 SMS and 0 MB of data. Dial *141*1# for details. WoW! Use R7 airtime to get R55+10MB.Dial *130*501#'
```

In most contexts, UTF-16-encoded data includes a [*Byte Order Mark* (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start, which is really just the [U+FEFF ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE](https://codepoints.net/U+FEFF) character, which tells decoders what byte order to use when decoding. When printed the character is essentially invisible.

You may have omitted it here, but if your data stream started with the bytes FE FF then that would definitely confirm you have big-endian UTF-16 data. If the stream started with FF FE then you have *little*-endian UTF-16 (byte order swapped) and also cut your sample at the wrong boundary here.

If the BOM is there then you don't have to specify the byte order manually; decoding with `utf-16` suffices:

```
>>> ('FEFF' + rawhex).decode('hex').decode('utf-16')
u'R0.00 airtime, 0 SMS and 0 MB of data. Dial *141*1# for details. WoW! Use R7 airtime to get R55+10MB.Dial *130*501#'
```

Comment: After posting and waiting for an answer I figured it is probably UTF-16, but the big and little endian formats I did not even consider. Didn't know about the BOM though. And no it did not include it at the start. Thank you this answer deserves half of my reputation(AKA the bounty) haha

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> print hex_string.decode('hex').decode('utf-16be')
R0.00 airtime, 0 SMS and 0 MB of data. Dial *141*1# for details. WoW! Use R7 airtime to get R55+10MB.Dial *130*501#
```